# How many different plates can be made if repetition of letters and digits are allowed?

Tags: probability

Some license plates are made using 3 letters followed by 2 digits. How many different plates can be made if repetition of letters and digits are allowed?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you state its source, show any work you have done, and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive a response that is appropriate to your skill level.

Answer (score 2):

Since any combination is valid, the multiplication principle applies. You have 26 choices for each letter and 10 choices for each digit. Thus the answer is $26^310^2$

Comment: Why 26 choices for each letter and 10 choices for each digit?

Comment: Seriously? Because there are 26 letters in the English alphabet and ten digits in the Hindu-Arabic numeral system.